# Having problem in creating new react app and error got "npm ERR! code ENOENT"

Tags: windows, npm, npx

```
PS G:\First react app> npx create-react-app first-app  
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@5.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) Y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

Creating a new React app in G:\First react app\first-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path G:\First react app\first-app\node_modules\.bin\parser.ps1
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\First react app\first-app\node_modules\.bin\parser.ps1'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JZ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-15T12_06_09_325Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JZ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-15T12_06_09_325Z-debug-1.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting first-app/ from G:\First react app
Done.
```

I tried to a new react app by npm create-react-app first-app

Comment: Is there any helpful information in the logs?  It might be a permission issue.

Comment: Nothing in the logs, even the "AppData" folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I get it, there was not enough space in the directory that cause this error. Finally, resolved the issue